# How to pass parameters to AngularJS resource?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have ASP.NET application with the form handled by AngularJS. There are 2 date-time pickers (fromDate and toDate variables) and check box that indicate if open dates are included (isOpenDatesIncluded).

The code looks as following:

1) In first AngularJS module:

```
SearchActionsApp.controller("ListController", function($scope, $location,$q, Actions, ActionDates, CounterAgents,Counteragents, AsyncTask) {
...

$scope.actionsQuery = {
    searchText: "",
    fromDate: new Date(moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY")),
    toDate: new Date(moment().add('d', 3).format("MM/DD/YYYY")),
    isOpenDatesIncluded: false,
...

ActionDates.query({ actionId: action.Id }, task.success, task.error);

...

}
```

2) In service.js:

```
.factory('ActionDates', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/RestApi/api/ActionDates', {});
})
```

3) On server side:

```
public IEnumerable<ActionDateItem> QueryActionDates(ActionDateQuery query)
{
    var sql = query.BuildSql();
    using (var cn = CreateSqlConnection())
    {
        return cn.Query<ActionDateItem>(sql, new
        {
            query.ActionId,
            query.IsOpenDatesIncluded,
            BeginDate = query.FromDate,
            EndDate = query.ToDate
        });
    }
}

public class ActionDateQuery
{
    public ActionDateQuery()
    {
        ActionId = -1;
        IsOpenDatesIncluded = false;
        FromDate = new DateTime(1980, 1, 1);
        ToDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    }

    public long ActionId { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpenDatesIncluded { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is the query returns the set of data from: 1980, 1, 1 to DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), but I need to return the data in range: fromDate - toDate, which I get from the client side. I need to pass 3 more parameters except from action.Id that is: fromDate, toDate and isOpenDatesIncluded.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add them to the arguments of the `query` method as follows:

```
query({
    actionId: action.Id,
    fromDate: $scope.actionsQuery.fromDate,
    ...
}, task.success, task.error)
```

If they are not pre-bound in the resouce, they will be appended to the request URL as query parameters.

*-- Edit --*

Also might I suggest using promises rather than callbacks, as it'll help with readability and chaining:

```
query({
    actionId: action.Id,
    fromDate: $scope.actionsQuery.fromDate,
    ...
}).$promise.then(function(response) {
    // success
}).catch(function(error) {
    // error
});
```

Comment: There's an error: "ReferenceError: actionsQuery is not defined".

Comment: You need to use `$scope` to access it. The code I posted is not meant to be an exact copy-paste usage example as I don't know how the rest of your code is structured. If your date control for "From Date" is bound to `actionsQuery.fromDate`, you'll access that variable using `$scope.actionsQuery.fromDate`.

Comment: Ok. That part is working now, which means I'm passing 3 more parameters. I suppose the next thing I need to change is the factory part in service.js file because I don't get new parameters on server side except Id. How to do that?

Comment: You need to check the request URL from angular and verify that the query parameters have been included on the request URL. If they are, you'll need to verify how the framework you're using for your server handles parameter binding.

Comment: The parameters attached to RestApi URL are correct, but I don't get them on server side.

Comment: Then it's most likely your parameter binding on your endpoint which is incorrect. Try adding the properties directly to the endpoint parameters as follows: `QueryActionDates(ActionDateQuery query, DateTime fromDate, etc...)`.

Comment: The only first parameter (actionId) has been passed successfully to server side, but other 3 haven't.

Comment: These comments are becoming long, so I think you should make a new question regarding the parameter binding since this question was specifically related to the angular resource parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ActionDates.query({ actionId: action.Id }, task.success, task.error);
```

Add the missing 3 parameters, like 
        {actionId: action.Id, fromDate: fromDate, etc}
and try to bind your parameters in the resource 
        $resource('/RestApi/api/ActionDates', { id: '@id', fromdate:'@fromdate', etc});

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't work:

.factory('ActionDates', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/RestApi/api/ActionDates',
        { actionId: '@actionId', isOpenDatesIncluded: '@isOpenDatesIncluded', fromDate: '@fromDate', toDate: '@toDate' });
    })

Comment: You only need to bind your properties if they are in the URL string. Otherwise they will be added as query parameters.